# Load nested JSON from S3 to Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have nested JSON structure like this:

```
{  
   "id":"1",
   "event":{  
       "eventid":"event-qcTUrDAThkbPsXi438rRk"
       "eventtype": 1
   }     
}
```

I need to map documents like this to a table with 3 fields: `id, eventid, eventtype`. Can I specify some mappings in Copy command like this:

```
COPY raw_data 
from 's3://foo/bar.json' 
with credentials as '' 
format as json 'auto';
```

Or shall I manually transform json docs to a flat view?

Answer (score 0):

The mapping from json to columns for this type of structure is handled by the jsonpaths option and file.  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-json.html

The COPY command looks something like:

```
copy sales
from 'emr://j-SAMPLE2B500FC/myoutput/json/' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole'
JSON 's3://mybucket/jsonpaths.json';
```

And the jsonpaths files looks like:

```
{
    "jsonpaths": [
       "$.id",
       "$.store.book.title",
    "$.location[0]"
    ]
}
```